# Swiping effect on background Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I would like to reproduce a sort a slider effect between background images like the website http://www.moveline.com/ does on the home page.

Example section bellow the title: "Mapping out the details for your next move".

I look at the code they use jQuery, RequireJS (2.1.4)

I try to isolate the code that is producing that effect but the JavaScript code has been compressed which make it really hard to understand (plus they use backbone).

Any idea how i could reproduce this nicely probably in jQuery with the help of some plugin?

Thank you

Comment: Go to www.jqueryui.com and look for a plugin. Someone has probably already done this and you can use what they did as a starting point. (and save a ton of time)

Comment: Yes Tim if you can suggest me any plugin? (I already looked)

Comment: The background animation effect doesn't require any plugin. It is using simple css transitions, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/32a4d/

Comment: Yes i am looking into the arrow animation as well

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle for almost what they're doing on their site http://jsfiddle.net/y29kR/2/

Html:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="menu-item" data-look-at="0 0">item1</div>
    <div class="menu-item" data-look-at="-40px -70px">item2</div>
    <div class="menu-item" data-look-at="-120px -30px">item3</div>
</div>
<div class="menu-content"></div>
```

CSS with css transitions on background-position

```
.items {
    float:left;
}
.menu-item {
    padding: 15px;
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70px;
}

.menu-content {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x350");
    background-position: center center;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background-position 600ms ease;
    -o-transition: background-position 600ms ease;
}
```

I'm using jQuery's .css method to detect hover event to produce the (almost) desired effect:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-item').hover(function(e) {
        var target = $(e.target),
            newPos = target.data("look-at");
        $('.menu-content').css({'background-position': newPos}); 
    });
    $('.items').mouseleave(function(e) {  
        $('.menu-content').css({'background-position': 'center center'}); 
    });
});
```